# How to select a proper prior to control the time dependent structure of variable?

Tags: bayesian, mixed-model, multilevel-analysis, prior, brms

I am new in analyzing RCT data and not familiar with the techniques that are always used in RCT analysis.

I am analyzing a dataset of a study: An RCT study with 50 participants; the data was collected at three time points, one was at time point one t1; one was at time point two t2; one was a follow-up. However, there were 10 people drop the experiment during time point t2.  Repeated measure ANOVA and multilevel model were applied. The formula in R syntax is as follows:

```
#anova
model <- aov(dependent_variable~ time*Group+Error(ID), data = data)

#multilevel model
mixed.lmer <- lmer(dependent_variable ~ time*Group + (1|ID), data = data)
```

Then, I tried to apply Bayesian linear mixed effect model with the default prior in R package `brms` since the sample size of the dataset is very small. Would you mind suggesting some prior to controlling the covariance structure between the `time` and `group` variable?
From my prior belief, after treatment, the score of the dependent variable should be lower than before. So I have thought of first-order autoregressive process prior to the `time*group` variable. However, the dataset only had three time points, is it still possible to apply AR(1) to the `time*group` variable?

Comment: How small is the dataset? In particular, how many unique IDs do you have? Also, an AR(1) process refers to how repeated observations of the dependent variable are correlated. It is not related to the predictors.